# High Sierra Group ACLs Broken?

Tags: high-sierra, permission, acl

So far as I've been able to determine, group ACLs appear to have no effect at all in macOS 10.13.3.

Given a group "editors" with members "joe" and "jane" who belong to no other groups, and a folder "Revisions" with the following permissions…

```
drwxr-x---+ 38 mary  reviewers  1292 Jan 26 13:37 Revisions
0: group:editors inherited allow list, add_file, search, delete, add_subdirectory, delete_child, readattr, writeattr, readextattr, writeextattr, readsecurity, writesecurity, chown, file_inherit, directory_inherit
```

…neither "joe" nor "jane" can access the folder.

It appears, though, that user ACLs work.  The following ACL, for example, does allow "joe" access:

```
drwxr-x---+ 38 mary  reviewers  1292 Jan 26 13:37 Revisions
0: user:joe inherited allow list, add_file, search, delete, add_subdirectory, delete_child, readattr, writeattr, readextattr, writeextattr, readsecurity, writesecurity, chown, file_inherit, directory_inherit
```

This appears to be true for both local and open directory users, on both local storage, AFP, and SMB shares.

It's such a massive, obvious flaw that I have trouble believing I'm not missing something obvious.  Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can't comprehend your problem! Group ACLs work perfectly in HS. Which command did you execute to append ACLs?

Comment: Obviously they don't work perfectly for me.  I can assign them using chmod or macOS Server and get the same non-result.  It's as though any entities belonging to a group don't exist.

Comment: Please cd to "Revisions" in Terminal on the server, enter `(IFS=/; set -f -- $PWD; for arg; do path="${path%/}/$arg"; paths+=("$path"); done; ls -dlae "${paths[@]}")` and post the result here. The output shows all ACLs (and POSIX permissions) of the path to "Revisions".

Comment: @klanomath Thanks for the suggestion.  The result exceeds the character limit here, but can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4eohny85zmrzuey/Revisions_ACLs.txt?dl=0

Comment: Is "ariel" member of the group "editors"? I may add it to your question - should I change names?

Comment: @Bryan The Dropbox link is broken. Do you still have the referenced file and, if that's the case, could you add it to your question?